# Concatenate filenames list with string

Tags: shell, powershell

I have this script that stores filenames into a text file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files" -Name |
  Out-File "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\FileList.txt"
```

The result is:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

I would like it to produce a list of PowerShell statements in a text file so that I could use them later like this:

```
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\file1.txt" -Value "foo"
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\file2.txt" -Value "foo"
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\file3.txt" -Value "foo"
Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\file4.txt" -Value "foo"
```

Is it possible to concatenate a string to the file name the way I need?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve here. Do you mean you want to produce a list of PowerShell statements in a file? What for? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I added in the question the purpose of the PowerShell statements, I think it may be more clear now for people that may see the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not sure whether I understand your question correctly but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files" | 
    % {
        "Add-Content -Path `"{0}`" -Value `"foo`"" -f $_.FullName
    } | Out-File "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\FileList.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure about what you're asking, but if I have it correct you want to get a list of files, add a line to the end of the file, and put the names of the files in text file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Add-Content -Value "foo"
        $_.Name
    } | Out-File "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Files\FileList.txt"
```

This is one possible way. It passes each item to `ForEach-Object`, where a value is added to the file, and the file name is sent to the pipeline. That gets piped into `Out-File` which writes the list.

There are many ways to achieve this; it's best to study and play with pipelining and then look at the various cmdlets and how they handle pipeline input.